# ¿Cómo actualizar y guardar nueva informacion en un fichero csv una vez fue creado?

Tags: python, csv, diccionarios

como puedo actualizar y guardar nueva informacion en un fichero csv una vez fue creado?

debajo les comparto el codigo con el que lo creo:

```
clientes = [
    ('1',1500,'leandro gonzalez','5498')
]

with open('clientes.csv','w' , newline='\n') as csvfile:
    campos = ['no de cuenta','balance','nombre cliente','numero de pin']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=campos)
    writer.writeheader()
    for no_de_cuenta,balance,nombre_cliente,numero_de_pin in clientes:
        writer.writerow({
            "no de cuenta":no_de_cuenta , 'balance':balance , 'nombre cliente':nombre_cliente , 'numero de pin':numero_de_pin  
        })

def balance():
    print(cliente['balance'])

def retiro(valor):
    cliente['balance'] = int(cliente['balance'])
    cliente['balance'] = cliente['balance']-valor

    balance()

def deposito(valor):
    cliente['balance'] = int(cliente['balance'])
    cliente['balance'] = cliente['balance']+valor

    balance()
```

utilice estas funciones para modificarla pero no se guarda en el archivo csv

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! podrias editar tu publicacion y ajustar el codigo como corresponde? de paso, en que lenguaje estas trabajando?

Comment: Estoy programando en Python

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi por favor has el [tour] y lee [ask] te aseguro que no te tomará mas de 5 minutos, y aprenderás las guías básicas del sitio para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Bienvenido a Stackoverflow, saludos!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses pandas, te será más fácil :D

Comment: Por favor, no subir código empleando imágenes, en lo posible subirlas como texto copiable al portapapeles.

Comment: Dónde se define la variable cliente?

Comment: @Japsz 
`with open('clientes.csv', newline='\n') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile )
     for cliente in reader:
         print(cliente["no de cuenta"],cliente['balance'],cliente['nombre cliente'],cliente['numero de pin'])`